# How quickly can this function be computed?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, liouville-function

I can show that $\lambda (n)=i^{\tau(n^{2})-1}$, where $\lambda (n)$ is the Liouville function, $\tau(n)$ is the divisor function, and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

My question is as stated, and what is the best it could be currently? Does the divisor function make it any easier?

I have little to no experience with computation complexity calculation.

Comment: It's $O(1)$. Maybe you mean to ask about its partial sums?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Perhaps. I'm really not clear at all how to measure computing time. This is what I mean to find. I'm curious to know if this form makes computation of the terms any easier than it's usual definition. Or if the summatory function's complexity is improved.

Comment: Oh, you want to know how quickly the function can be computed? I thought you were asking how quickly the function grows.

Comment: Lol, yes. As I said, I have no experience in this area. Forgive my ignorance in this area. I'm wondering if its easier to calculate Liouville function for large n with this form.

Comment: No, it's no easier to calculate the Liouville function this way. No matter what you do you can't get around the fact that calculating the Liouville function is at least as hard as determining whether $n$ is prime, which is hard, although now known to be doable in polynomial time (in $\log n$).

Comment: Thought so. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually,
the definition is
$\lambda (n)=(-1)^{\Omega(n)}
$
where $\Omega(n)$
is the number of
prime factors of $n$
counted with multiplicity.

If
$n
=\prod p_n^{k_i}
$
then
$\Omega(n)
=\sum k_i
$.

Therefore the time
to compute 
$\Omega(n)$
is at most the time needed
to factor $n$,
so
you can look at
articles like this
to get an idea of
what is currently known:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Yes, but my version doesn't have bigomega, it has the divisor function. I was wondering if this would make it easier.

Comment: From what I have seen, it doesn't seem to. But nobody seems to know for sure.

Comment: Nobody seems to know for sure?

Comment: They don't know if it is less difficult than factoring.

Comment: Who is "they"? Were you referring to people you were with?

Comment: Comments I have seen in places like Wikipedia. Do a Google or similar search and look at some of the results.

Comment: I still have yet to find this relationship anywhere, so I think I might of actually found a new representation of the Liouville function. I don't think I can find results in this form. I don't think it will make it any easier to compute, but at the same time, intuition tells me it might be easier to compute the number of divisors of $n^{2}$ easier than the number of factors of n.

Comment: why dont you just write code and compare the time needed? That would give a first insight.

Comment: @MrYouMath I don't know how to write code, I'm only concerned with finding new mathematical expressions. Wolfram Alpha satisfies my computing needs. I'm just trying to see if it helps others. And to have a concrete answer if someone asks me the same question of my formula.